# Count number of times a letter is in a word

Tags: clojure

I have the word `describe`, and I want to see how many times each letter appears in the word. Eg "e" appears twice, "d" appears once etc

I have tried

```
    (for [letter (map str (seq describe))] 
      (count (re-seq letter describe)))
```

But I get the error

```
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.regex.Pattern  clojure.core/re-matcher (core.clj:4667)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is `letter` an RE?

Comment: letter is a character, not a string. to make a regex pattern you could do `(re-pattern (str letter))` but you can solve the stated problem better using `frequencies` as given by the answer by Taylor.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`frequencies`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/frequencies) to count the frequency at which each character appears in the string, returning a map like this:

```
(frequencies "ababacdefg")
=> {\a 3, \b 2, \c 1, \d 1, \e 1, \f 1, \g 1}
```

This works because the string is being treated as a sequence of characters. `frequencies` can be used on general collections:

```
(frequencies [1 1 2 3])
=> {1 2, 2 1, 3 1}
```

The key is the value being counted, and the value is the frequency.